# Nuances between "навстречу / в / на" as a preposition following the verb "отправиться"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> отправиться **навстречу** приключениям

Given the meaning of the base word "встреча", I'm assuming that "отправиться навстречу" is somewhat nuanced compared to "отправиться в / на".

> отправиться **в** приключения
>
> отправиться **на** приключения

I don't suppose "к" works here, does it?

> отправиться **к** приключениям

Incidentally, I wonder if "приключение" should always be in the plural when coupled with "отправиться".

---

On a side note: another similar phrase comes to mind:

> отправиться **в путешествие**

Comment: Is it a question about **навстречу** or about using **в** and **на** prepositions when talking about abstract things? A nuance of the first is well described by a dictionary - it means *towards*. For the second I'm afraid it is more a convention. You say "**на войну**" and "**в поход**" and not other way round. And no, в/к/на приключения doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexVB Hi. No, it is not about the prepositions themselves, but the possible nuances when coupled with the verb "отправиться". Because at least "навстречу" and "в" seem to work equally well with "отправиться".

Comment: Why do you think so?  I can't come up with an example when you can use both.

Comment: "в" means "into", it implies you can say later "i am within XXXX". So it works with "в поход" but not with "в приключение". Yep, it is conventional, I can't word some formal rule for it. К also implies with some object near your journey end, or some person owning the location. "пойдём к Петровым" - "Let's go to the Petrovs". "Иванов - к доске" - can a teacher call a pupil to come to the chalkboard for publicly solving a task. So, basically it is about preposition-noun coupling, not preposition-verb

Comment: @AlexVB ya.ru -> "навстречу войне" - a lot of. So while it is not the same as на войну, those both prepositions can be used

Comment: @Arioch My last comment was about *в* preposition.

Comment: навстречу шторму / в шторм. Okay, here в means where-is rather than where-to, so you may argue it is kinda another preposition, homonym :-D  /// навстречу лету / дверь в лето /// навстречу истории / уйти в историю (ы вечность)

Comment: @AlexVB This question occurred to me when I came across "отправиться **навстречу приключениям**" and "отправиться **в путешествие**".

Comment: Hавстрeчу is more about APPROACHING, about FACING something, giving something (good or bad) a chance to happen. В is about a destination point, about finally arriving, about being there. It is not said in Russian you are within an adventure, в приключении. So, you can only give to a trouble a chance to catch you, to step out into a trouble's reach, навстречу.

Comment: Offtopic. "Started learning Russian January 2018" ehh... really? and you query such a language nuancing already??? Those japs are positively crazy! O_O

Answer (score 2):

"Отправиться навстречу" is a absolutely correct for "приключениям", but it is a phraseologysm. Отправиться навстречу опасности, отправиться навстречу судьбе, отправиться навстречу геморрою, отправиться навстречу мечтаниям.

Answer (score 2):

`"Отправиться навстречу приключениям"` is a proper phrase for embarking on an adventure.

`"Отправиться в приключения"` is not proper. "Пуститься в приключения" can be used.

`"Отправиться на приключения"` is proper, but nuanced differently from "... навстречу ...". "... навстречу ..." implies that the adventures would be unexpected, with overall positive sense. "... на ..." implies that adventures would be of a well-known sort, with overall negative sense, for example, a nightlong drinking trip through seedy bars.

`"Отправиться к приключениям"` is hardly proper as it is. "Отправиться к **новым** приключениям" would be better.

Comment: The phrase **"Отправиться на приключения"** occurs in internet posts. But I didn't find a single occurrence in [RusCorpora](http://www.ruscorpora.ru)